# How would I add a warm, golden glow to a photo?

Tags: post-processing, effect, warmth

How would you define the look and colour scheme of these stills ([1](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm967612672/tt0278823?ref_=ttmi_mi_all_sf_4), [2](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm950835456/tt0278823?ref_=ttmd_md_pv), [3](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm128751872/tt0278823?ref_=ttmd_md_nxt), [4](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm1001167104/ch0019609?ref_=nmmd_rg_md1)) from the 2002 movie *[Hollywood Ending](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278823/mediaindex?ref_=ttmd_md_sm)*, with respect to highlights, shadows, mid tones, white balance, contrast, saturation, etc.?

Is there a way to apply this look, and if there is how can it be done?

I do know that a lot of this golden glow gets enhanced by the colour scheme of production and costume design of this film.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this look? What exactly did you try and what did you achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The pics are very well thought and was taken with carefully setting the background/foreground colour schema, lighting, etc. 
highlights, shadows, midtones, and contrast is very hard to define just by looking at the pics (for me atleast)

But when I have to reproduce the effect I do the following

1) take the picture in well light natural light area. if I need more light I go for tungsten filament lamps and gold reflectors and in RAW

2) post processing

- increase contrast by 1 unit
- reduce shadows by 1 unit
- and increase the temperature to the kind of yellow wash you need

for the glow there are standard filters available but they blur the image a bit so I personally don't use it.

Hope this helps .